# Fibre Channel Ports and Tape Library

Tags: backup, tape, fibre-channel, tapedrive, qlogic

I am looking for advice rather then fix my issue.

What should fibre channel port settings be? Currently F_ports,

I have a qlogic 5800 sanbox switch connected to quantum scalar i40 lto7 library over fibre channel.

My backup product P5, speeds backing up a NAS a rubbish, will never finish!

If you have a backup library connected to a fibre switch, what ports settings do you have on the fibre port switch?

What speeds do you get backing up? mine are 20-35mb/s

Thanks

Comment: There's a LOT more detail needed I'm afraid, just fill this with as much detail as you can please.

Comment: backup server has a 10GB fibre card, connected to core switch, NAS connected via 10GB fibre to core switch. Backup server is running Centos 6.5, Prestor P5 backup software.

Comment: Fibre-Channel doesn't run at 10Gbps - 1/2/4/8/16 & 32Gbps yes, 10Gbps no, unless you're talking FCoE - again, more, and accurate, detail please.

Comment: Edit** Backup server Centos 6.5 with 10GB FCoE, Qlogic HBA running @4gbps.

Comment: Edit** Backup server Centos 6.5 with 10gb FCoE, Qlogic HBA running 4gbps. NAS is connected via 10gb FCoE, NAS and Backup Server on same vlan. Tape drives running 4GB,  I have manages to get backups to run at 40mb/s by forcing fabric switch ports 4GB. But that is still not optimum.

Answer (score 1):

I had performance problems with an IBM TS3100 a while ago. My troubleshooting log from that contains the following:

- The tape drive needed to be set to N-port mode.
- The tape drive had an 8Gbps FC interface while the backup server and FC switch had 16Gbps ones. I had issues with timeouts until I set the same speed across the line (effectively lowering the max throughput for the backup server)
- In the end it turned out I also had a bad FC cable that caused massive amounts of retransmissions.

After that I saw the kind of speeds I expected - Veeam backup copies to tape (in other words few but large files) averaging around 235 MiB/s over the duration of a job.